# Считывание содержимого файла C# и SystemOutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы, io

Разрабатываю приложение для архивации. для записи в файл/чтения использую стандартную библиотеку System.IO. При считывании строки программа способна оперировать информацией, однако, при подгрузке из файла этой же информации программа кидает SystemOutOfMemoryException. С чем это может быть связано?

Функция добавления файла в виде строки:

```
        private async void btnAddElement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "All|*.*|Image|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|Video|*.mp4";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                currentFile.Add(FileToBase64(ofd.FileName));
                names.Add(GetFileName(ofd.FileName).Replace(' ', specSymbol));
                MessageBox.Show(names[names.Count - 1]);
                if (withName)
                    await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllLines(resPath, ConstructContent(currentFile, names)));
                else
                    await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllLines(resPath, FilesToBase64(currentFile)));
                WriteToLog("\"" + ofd.FileName + "\" added successfuly.", new StackTrace());
                MessageBox.Show("\"" + ofd.FileName + "\" added successfuly.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error on new file adding: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.Source);
            WriteToLog("Error on new file adding", new StackTrace(), ex);
        }
    }
```

`ConstructContent` здесь соединяет всю нужную информацию в строки для записи.
Функция отделения содержимого файла для работы (считанного в сыром виде через ReadAllLines):

```
List<string> GetContent(List<string> fileLines)
    {
        List<string> base64s = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                base64s.Add(fileLines[i].Split()[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GetContent(): Index-" + i + ";" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return base64s;
    }
```

Прошу заметить, что программа не получает огромных объемов информации, так как при добавлении строки функционирует нормально, а вот считывание из файла, почему-то, требует огромного количества памяти. Исключение получается в результате выполнения этой команды в GetContent:

```
fs.Add(cf[i].Split()[0]);
```

Comment: Есть асинхронная версия этого метода `WriteAllLines`, поэтому его обертывать в `Task.Run` не нужно, а по делу, если ошибка вылетает в `LoadFile()` может его стоит добавить в вопрос

Comment: @ExplodingKitten `LoadFile()` был закомментирован, т.к. эффективнее добавлять строки синхронно в файл и память программы. Наверное, стоит убрать эту строку, дабы не путать.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Суть в том, что функция AddElement не имеет причастности к SystemOutOfMemory напрямую, поскольку файлы добавляются успешно. Проблема возникает лишь при считывании из файла `File.ReadAllLines` и затем обработке в `GetContent`.

Comment: Кхм, а вас не смущает `System.Windows.Forms` и `WPF`?

Comment: Нужно больше кода, показывайте все испольуземые обработчиком события методы целиком.

Comment: И главный вопрос - зачем здесь вообще Base64? Зачем вы храните двоичные файлы в строках? Какую задачу решает ваш код? Пошагово. `для архивации` - каким образом эта цель достигается?